# A 'for' loop that looks at numbers and assigns them a Boolean statement it can compare several inputs

Tags: c++, for-loop, boolean

Would someone please look at the below code and see why it works most of the time but not always?

It works when I input something like `"7 1000 1002 896 897 1004 987 960"`, it shows `Unallowed value(s)` like it's supposed to.

But if I input `"7 896 1003 1004 899 897 898 906"`, it should say `Unallowed value(s)`, but it works periodically.

```
int main() {
    int inputCount;

    bool allAllowed;
    int range;
    cin >> inputCount;
    cin >> range;

    if ((range >= 900) && (range <= 1000)) {
        allAllowed = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < inputCount; ++i) {
            cin >> range;
            if ((range >= 900) && (range <= 1000)) {
                allAllowed = 0;
            }
            else if ((range < 900) || (range > 1000)) {
             //   i = inputCount + 1;
                allAllowed = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else if ((range < 900) || (range > 1000))  {
      allAllowed = 1;
    }


    if (allAllowed) {
        cout << "Only allowed values" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unallowed value(s)" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you pretend that a complete stranger, who knows nothing at all, walks off the street and is standing in front of you. What is the concise, coherent question that you would ask this stranger, that you believe this stranger will understand and might have an answer to? After rereading the above, I still don't understand what's asked here. What does "works most of the time" mean? What is "allowed values" mean?

Comment: Step through your code and you will quickly have your answer. I just did it mentally with 3 iterations and found your problem. You can do it with a debugger and see in real time why it’s happening.

Comment: allowed values is one of its outputs it is supposed to state if you are within its range... Otherwise it is not allowed.. Another thing is yes I tested it.. it literally works 5/7 times so if you can find another meaning for that please tell me.

Comment: `896` is less than `900`, so `else if ((range < 900) || (range > 1000))` branch is taken. In that branch, `allAllowed = 1;` is set unconditionally, without ever looking at the rest of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial value of range, 896, isn't between 900 and 1000 and satisfies the condition
`else if ((range < 900) || (range > 1000))`, making `allAllowed = 1`,
meaning it will always return "Only allowed values".

Something else you should consider is that your program will only consider the last inputted number to determine `allAllowed` within the condition `if ((range >= 900) && (range <= 1000))`